# Compare two folders with rsync and copy all new and changed content

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I have two folders with images that looks like this, they have over 1GB of images inside so just copy and replace images_remote with images_local would take a long time and i'm looking for a better way to handle this.

What i'm looking for is to check what content has been changed or is missing from images_local compared to images_remote and copy it over to images_local.

The main goal is to make images_local be exactly the same as images_remote without having to copy and replace everything.

The folder structure looks something like this

```
images_local                    
  image_1
    1.png
  image_2
    2.png

images_remote 
  image_1
    1.png
  image_2
    2.png
  image_3
    3.png
```

This is what i have done right now, and it works in some ways but it does not handle that content might be removed or changed from images_remote and then "fix" images_local.

```
rsync -rvcm --compare-dest=/home/images_local/ /remote/images_remote/ /home/images_local/
```

Comment: `rsync -rvcm --delete /remote/images_remote/ /home/images_local/` ?

Comment: @jhnc Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly. If you could type this as an answer i will accept and upvote it.